# Amazon In-App Not Proceeding

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Amazon In app Purchasing in android. First I downloaded the sample code from Amazon "ButtonClicker" from this site. When I run the code on my Kindle Fire I received these messages on my Eclipse Logcat:

After sending request nothing happens. No response received.

Is there any problem due to SKUs? But no error is being shown on Invalid SKU. Please help me out in solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you registered the Amazon ResponseReceiver in the manifest? If you haven't than you will not be able to catch any response.

```
    <receiver android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.ResponseReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action
                android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also check the **amazon.sdktester.json** which you must have put in mnt/sdcard folder. Make sure it is not missing and does not has json compilation errors.

Comment: Thankyou for help.Yes i have register the response but i did not know how to put the amazon.sdktester.json in mnt/sdcard??

Comment: now i have push the json file in the mnt/sdcard folder. but it displaying the same Logcat. did not solve the problem..:(

Comment: After putting the json in the mnt/sdcard folder this issue should have resolved. I wonder that while testing your project you device is connected and it might have 'USB storage' ON. In that case your SD card is not accessible by the Game and your json wont be used. Switch off the USB storage.

Comment: thanks for the help again. yes i know that but how to off the usb debugging mode of kindle fire? i did not see any usb debugging mode in kindle fire..